# Check-in Copied Solution to TFS (visualstudio.com)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

To start off, I've never used TFS (or any source control) before.  Since Microsoft announced free Team Foundation Service on visualstudio.com, I thought I'd try it, for both the version control and using it as another backup.  So here's what I have going on...

I have a solution that I've got checked in at xxxxx.visualstudio.com, and I wanted to make a copy of the solution, with some minor changes, and save it as a different solution on vs.com as well.  I copied the local version of the solution to a new directory, deleted the .vsssc file (through experimentation, I was thinking this was how it tracked changes - maybe I'm wrong), created a new solution on vs.com, made my local changes, and tried to check in.  Nope.

I've done lots of unbinding, rebinding, tried add to source control, and a bunch of other stuff - so much that I'm sure I wouldn't be able to tell you all of it.  I used tfsdeleteproject to delete and start over, all to no avail.

What I get is "One or moreof the pending changes no longer exists or was modified.  The list of pending changes has been refreshed and is now current.  Please inspect the list of pending changes and try your operation again."  But I don't know what I'm supposed to look for in inspecting the changes, and when I try again, I get the same message.

I'm thinking that the best thing to do is to make my project forget that it was ever a part of TFS, delete the project on VS.com, create a new project on vs.com, and add the now-suffering-from-amnesia project to source control on vs.com.  But I can't seem to figure out how to make a solution forget that it was part of source control.  Is there a way?

Comment: Why do you want to make a Copy of it? Is it to track release versions or to allow you to work on some new features?

Comment: Because they are separate releases.

Comment: Then using Branches, have a read up on the info in Hamid's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the project to forget about the Team Foundation Server, edit your solution file and remove the section starting with "GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)."

If I understand you right, your need is to  to keep the original version of the solution and do some changes in a copy so that your original code base is still stable. The way to do it in TFS is to branch your solution to separate branch.

Here is a good link about branching http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx.

Microsoft Visual Studio ALM Rangers have written a very good guide about branching to cover different scenarios. http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks - I'll look at that when I get home from work tonight.  Or...  Tonight's busy - probably tomorrow.

Comment: That did part of it.  I also had to delete the *vss files from each project in the solution, as well as the solution, remove a few elements from each project file having to do with vss, and unbind using File | Source Control | Advanced | Change Source Control.